# JavaScript summing large integers

Tags: javascript, biginteger

In JavaScript I would like to create the binary hash of a large boolean array (54 elements) with the following method:

```
function bhash(arr) {
   for (var i = 0, L = arr.length, sum = 0; i < L; sum += Math.pow(2,i)*arr[i++]); 
   return sum;
}
```

In short: it creates the smallest integer to store an array of booleans in. Now my problem is that javascript apparently uses **floats** as default. The maximum number I have to create is 2^54-1 but once javascript reaches 2^53 it starts doing weird things:

```
9007199254740992+1 = 9007199254740994
```

Is there any way of using integers instead of floats in javascript? Or large integer summations?

Comment: Javascript not only uses a floating-point type as default, it doesn't *have* any other numerical type - decidedly not a "good part" of the language.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

JavaScript uses floating point internally.

[What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-to)

In other words you can't use more than 53 bits. In some implementations you may be limited to 31.

Try storing the bits in more than one variable, use a string, or get a [bignum library](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber), or if you only need to deal with integers, a [biginteger library](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js).

Comment: It worked when I added that library and edited the function as follows: `function bhash(arr) {
  for (var i = 0, L = arr.length, sum = new BigNumber("0"); i < L; sum = new BigNumber(Math.pow(2,i)*arr[i++]).add(sum));
  return sum;
 }`

Comment: see also http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html for a comprehensive explanation and workarounds, http://2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html, https://github.com/rauschma/strint https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Answer (score 13):

`BigInt` is being added as a native feature of JavaScript.

```
typeof 123;
// → 'number'
typeof 123n;
// → 'bigint'
```

Example:

```
const max = BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
const two = 2n;
const result = max + two;
console.log(result);
// → '9007199254740993'
```

Comment: Thank you. What does the 'n' stand for?

Comment: instead of calling BigInt() as function, n suffix can be added to explicitly tell the interpreter to treat an integer as BigInt not a Number.

Answer (score 5):

javascript now has [experimental support for `BigInt`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint).
At the time of writing only chrome supports this.

[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=bigint) has no entry yet.

`BigInt` can be either used with a constructor, e.g. `BigInt(20)` or by appending `n`, e.g. `20n`

Example:

```js
const max = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;

console.log('javascript Number limit reached', max + 1 === max + 2) // true;

console.log('javascript BigInt limit reached', BigInt(max) + 1n === BigInt(max) + 2n); // false
```

Comment: It's now widely supported [CanIUse:BigInt](https://caniuse.com/?search=bigint)

Answer (score 3):

No. Javascript only has one numeric type. You've to code yourself or use a large integer library (and you cannot even overload arithmetic operators).

## Update

This was true in 2010... now (2019) a BigInt library is being standardized and will most probably soon arrive natively in Javascript and it will be the second numeric type present (there are typed arrays, but - at least formally - values extracted from them are still double-precision floating point numbers).

Comment: It's now widely supported [CanIUse:BigInt](https://caniuse.com/?search=bigint)

Answer (score 2):

So while attempting one of the leetcode problem I have written a function which takes two numbers in form of string and returns the sum of those numbers in form of string.
**(This doesn't work with negative numbers though we can modify this function to cover that)**

```
var addTwoStr = function (s1, s2) {
s1 = s1.split("").reverse().join("")
s2 = s2.split("").reverse().join("")
var carry = 0, rS = '', x = null
if (s1.length > s2.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
        let s = s1[i]
        if (i < s2.length) {
            x = Number(s) + Number(s2[i]) + carry
            rS += String((x % 10))
            carry = parseInt(x/10)
        } else {
            if (carry) {
                x = Number(s) + carry
                rS += String((x % 10))
                carry = parseInt(x/10)
            } else {
                rS += s
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    for (let i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
        let s = s2[i]
        if (i < s1.length) {
            x = Number(s) + Number(s1[i]) + carry
            rS += String((x % 10))
            carry = parseInt(x/10)
        } else {
            if (carry) {
                x = Number(s) + carry
                rS += String((x % 10))
                carry = parseInt(x/10)
            } else {
                rS += s
            }
        }
    }
}
if (carry) {
    rS += String(carry)
}
return rS.split("").reverse().join("")
}
```

Example: addTwoStr('120354566', '321442535')
Output: "441797101"

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation of large integer arithmetic (also using BigInt.js) is available at [www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/100digitbigintcalculator.htm](http://www.javascripter.net/math/calculators/100digitbigintcalculator.htm). Supports the operations + - * / as well as remainder, GCD, LCM, factorial, primality test, next prime, previous prime.

Answer (score 0):

There are various BigInteger Javascript libraries that you can find through googling. e.g. http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.html

Comment: I did the following: `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="BigInt.js"></SCRIPT>` but the cosole gave me an error > invalid array length: "buff=new Array(k);"

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into a byte length limit on your system. I'd take the array of booleans, convert it to an array of binary digits ([true, false, true] => [1,0,1]), then join this array into a string "101", then use parseInt('101',2), and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [(yet another) wrapper around Leemon Baird's BigInt.js](http://www.cjandia.com/2012/06/x-calc/libs/bigint.js.txt)

It is used in this [online demo of a big integer calculator in JavaScript](http://www.cjandia.com/2012/06/x-calc/) which implements the usual four operations + - * /, the modulus (%), and four builtin functions : the square root (sqrt), the power (pow), the recursive factorial (fact) and a memoizing Fibonacci (fibo).

Answer (score 0):

```
/** --if you want to show a big int as your wish use install and require this module
 * By using 'big-integer' module is easier to use and handling the big int numbers than regular javascript
 * https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer
*/

let bigInt = require('big-integer');

//variable: get_bigInt
let get_bigInt = bigInt("999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999");

let arr = [1, 100000, 21, 30, 4, BigInt(999999999999), get_bigInt.value];

console.log(arr[6]); // Output: 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999n

//Calculation
console.log(arr[6] + 1n); // +1
console.log(arr[6] + 100n); // +100
console.log(arr[6] - 1n); // -1
console.log(arr[6] - 10245n); // -1000n

console.log((arr[6] * 10000n) + 145n - 435n);
```