# Why does console.log(10150141932135203) print 10150141932135204 in both Firefox and Chrome and how to I deal with large integer values like these?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, node.js

I was trying to figure out why one of our clients on Facebook was having issues and I traced it to the number 10150141932135203 turning into 10150141932135204 giving us rather unexpected results.

```
$ node
> 10150141932135203
10150141932135204
> 10150141932135204
10150141932135204
> 10150141932135205
10150141932135204
> 10150141932135206
10150141932135206
> 10150141932135207
10150141932135208
> 10150141932135208
10150141932135208
> 10150141932135209
10150141932135208
> 10150141932135210
10150141932135210
```

How can I deal with integer numbers of this size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript summing large integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557509/javascript-summing-large-integers) and many, many others

Comment: @AdamBernier I'm not even doing arithmetic, but yes maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the numbers are bigger than what the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) spec allows (2<sup>53</sup>), they will lose precision as your examples demonstrate.

You could use a [Binary Coded Decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) library for JavaScript, e.g. [BCMathJs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bcmath-js/).

This, of course, is only applicable if you need to perform arithmetic on the numbers. If not, keep them as strings.

Comment: That library will become crazy popular now then when every single Facebook application will be unable to reliably talk to Facebook UIDs of that size.

Comment: @KitSunde If you are not performing arithmetic, just keep them as strings.

Comment: You also have libraries purely for integers of any size which may be faster eg https://github.com/silentmatt/javascript-biginteger

Comment: @alex Seems like the way to go. I also had to get HTML data attributes via `$("body").attr("data-page-id")` rather than `$("body").data("page-id")` because of this.

Comment: @KitSunde Yeah, the helpful *turn into a native type from guessing* sometimes isn't too helpful with `data()`.