# How to add two big numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two text boxes. Each will take input up to thousand digits.

Now i want to add these two numbers. My question is what data type should i use to store the result?

I have tried this:

```
<script>
   var x = 'Thousand digit of number'
    var y = 'Thousand digit of number'
    var z = x + y
</script>
```

but i am getting result in exponential form. How to store the result and display it?

Comment: Use one of the bug number libs out there.

Comment: how big is your number

Comment: upto thousand digit @REHANSHIKKALGAR

Comment: i tried to put the number but it was not posting my question thats why i changed it. @LKTN.25

Comment: ok. that explains a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript summing large integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557509/javascript-summing-large-integers)

Comment: Javascript will display anything larger than `10e21` in exponential form. My browser and Node.js both return `Infinity` for anything larger than (approximately) `1.7e308`. Javascript is not a good platform for dealing with very, very large numbers.

Comment: The biggest number you can work safely with in JavaScript is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.

What are you calculating that takes 10 * googol sized numbers? Can it be simplified?

There are libraries like http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/ that deals with big numbers in JavaScript

Comment: Try `number3 = (number1 + number2) ` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input the numbers as string and add each characters each other as array something like this:

```
 function add() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
        var x = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
        var len;
        var lenx = x.length;
        var leny = y.length;
        var x1,y1,rem,div=0;
        if(lenx>leny) len = lenx; else len = leny;

        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
            if(i>=lenx) x1  = 0;
            else x1 = parseInt(x[lenx-i-1]);
            if(i>=leny) y1 = 0;
            else y1 = parseInt(y[leny-i-1]);
            rem = (x1+y1+div)%10;
            div = Math.floor((x1 + y1+div)/10);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = rem + document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
        }
       if(div>0){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = div + document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
       }
    }
```

Here the code: https://jsfiddle.net/mtsL1k2x/5/

Note: this is only for natural numbers. You can modify depending on your inputs

Answer (score 13):

Yet another solution, because it's faster and cleaner.

```
function add(A, B) {
  const AL = A.length
  const BL = B.length
  const ML = Math.max(AL, BL)

  let carry = 0, sum = ''

  for (let i = 1; i <= ML; i++) {
    let a = +A.charAt(AL - i)
    let b = +B.charAt(BL - i)

    let t = carry + a + b
    carry = t/10 |0
    t %= 10

    sum = (i === ML && carry)
      ? carry*10 + t + sum
      : t + sum
  }

  return sum
}
```

```
> add(
'9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999',
'999999999999999999999999999999999999999'
)

> "10000000000000000000000000000000000000999999999999999999999999999999999999998"
```

Comment: return sum.startsWith("0") ? sum.substring(1):sum;
To avoid starting with any ZERO

Comment: @Malik With what values did it return a leading `0` to you?

Answer (score 7):

Use BigInt as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56370672/641913

```js
const z = BigInt(x) + BigInt(y);

console.log(z.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution not so different from others you can find in the internet (**consider that it doesn't work with negative numbers!**):

```js
function sums(arg1, arg2) {
 var sum = "";
 var r = 0;
 var a1, a2, i;

 // Pick the shortest string as first parameter and the longest as second parameter in my algorithm
 if (arg1.length < arg2.length) {
  a1 = arg1;
  a2 = arg2;
 }
 else {
  a1 = arg2;
  a2 = arg1;
 }
 a1 = a1.split("").reverse();
 a2 = a2.split("").reverse();

 // Sum a1 and a2 digits
 for (i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
  var t = ((i < a1.length) ? parseInt(a1[i]) : 0) + parseInt(a2[i]) + r;
  
  sum += t % 10;

  r = t < 10 ? 0 : Math.floor(t / 10);
 }
 // Append the last remain
 if (r > 0)
  sum += r;

 sum = sum.split("").reverse();
 
 // Trim the leading "0"
 while (sum[0] == "0")
  sum.shift();

 return sum.length > 0 ? sum.join("") : "0";
}

// Test
function testEquals(expected, actual) {
 if (expected == actual)
  console.log("OK: " + expected);
 else
  console.error("ERROR: " + expected + " != " + actual);
}

testEquals("100", sums("99", "1"));
testEquals("100", sums("00099", "0001"));
testEquals("10000000000", sums("9999999999", "1"));
testEquals("10000010101", sums("9999999999", "10102"));
testEquals("0", sums("0", "0"));
testEquals("1", sums("0", "1"));
testEquals("9", sums("8", "1"));
testEquals("9", sums("1", "8"));
testEquals("10000000000000000000000000000000000000000", sums("9999999999999999999999999999999999999999", "1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use a big number library like https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html , or you can use something lighter weight (but easy to understand) like http://www.discoversdk.com/knowledge-base/arbitrary-length-integer-addition-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to do this without using BigInt or any third-party Library, then I don't think you need to convert to an array, you can use the charAt() function to add the individual characters at each point in the string. You would have to use the for loop starting from its maximum value and reducing till its lowest. The code snippet is below;

```
function add(a, b) {
let sum='';
 let z,x;
 let r=0;
 if (a.length>=b.length){
   z=a;
   x=b;
 }
 else{
   z=b;
   x=a;
 };
 let p=x.length;
 for (let i=z.length;i>0;i--){
   let t=((p>0)?parseInt(x.charAt(p-1)):0)+parseInt(z.charAt(i-1))+r;
   sum=(t%10)+sum;
   r=t<10?0:Math.floor(t/10);
   p=p-1;
 };
 if (r>0){sum=r+sum};
 return sum;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add(a, b) {
    a = a.split("").reverse();
    b = b.split("").reverse();
    let maxLen=Math.max(a.length, b.length);
    let sum = [];
    let remainder = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) {
      let x = parseInt(a[i]) ? parseInt(a[i]) : 0;
      let y = parseInt(b[i]) ? parseInt(b[i]) : 0;
      let digit = (x + y + remainder) % 10;
      remainder = Math.floor((x + y + remainder) / 10);
      sum.unshift(digit);
    }
    if (remainder) {sum.unshift(remainder)}
    
    return sum.join("");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add(a, b){
  let sum = "";
  let remainder = 0;
  a = a.split("");
  b = b.split("");
  while (a.length || b.length || remainder) {
    remainder += ~~a.pop() + ~~b.pop();
    sum = (remainder % 10) + sum;
    remainder = remainder > 9;
  }
  return sum;
}

const sum = add("9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999", "999999999999999999999999999999999999999");

console.log({sum})
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function add(x, y) {
    //this function adds two extremely large numbers, negative and/or positive
    var temp, borrow=false, bothNeg=false, oneNeg=false, neg=false;
    if (x < 0 && y < 0) { bothNeg = true; x = -x; y = -y; } 
    else if (x < 0 || y < 0) {
        oneNeg = true;
        if (Math.abs(x) == Math.abs(y)) { x = 0; y = 0; }
        else if (x < 0 && Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(y)) { neg = true; x = -x; y = -y; }
        else if (x < 0 && Math.abs(x) < Math.abs(y)) { temp = y; y = x; x = temp; }
        else if (y < 0 && Math.abs(x) < Math.abs(y)) { neg = true; temp = y; y = -x; x = -temp; }
    }
    x = parseInt(x*1000000000/10).toString();
    y = parseInt(y*1000000000/10).toString();
    var lenx=x.length, leny=y.length, len=(lenx>leny)?lenx:leny, sum="", div=0, x1, y1, rem;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        x1 = (i >= lenx) ? 0 : parseInt(x[lenx-i-1]);
        y1 = (i >= leny) ? 0 : parseInt(y[leny-i-1]);
        y1 = (isNaN(y1)) ? 0 : y1;
        if (oneNeg) y1 = -y1;
        if (borrow) x1 = x1 - 1;
        if (y < 0 && x1 > 0 && Math.abs(x1) >= Math.abs(y1)) { borrow=false; div=0; }
        if (y < 0 && y1 <= 0 && (x1 < 0 || Math.abs(x1) < Math.abs(y1))) { borrow=true; rem=(x1+y1+div+10)%10; div=10; }
        else { rem=(x1+y1+div)%10; div=Math.floor((x1+y1+div)/10); }
        sum = Math.abs(rem).toString() + sum;
    }
    if (div > 0) sum = div.toString() + sum;
    sum = parseFloat(sum*10/1000000000);
    if (bothNeg || neg) sum = -sum;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: How does it work? This will not give an expected result `add(9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999,999999999999999999999999999999999999999)`

Answer (score -3):

```
 <body>
<p>Click the button to calculate x.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<br/>
<br/>Enter first number:
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="text1">Enter second number:
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="text2">
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
    var x = +y + +z;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sanjeevgaut/mtsL1k2x/

Comment: Can you explain why would `+y` and `+z` make a difference ?

Comment: `input up to thousand digits`

Comment: If you will not put + then it will treat as string, If we add +var then only it will treat as number.

Comment: hey i hope my solution is working fine? I have share the working link also.

Comment: he doesnt want to get result in exponential form. try to input large numbers