# Adding two big numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to add the following numbers using javascript;
`76561197960265728` + `912447736`

Sadly, because of rounding in javascript it will not get the correct number, I need the number as a string.

I've tried removing the last few digits using substr and then adding the two numbers together and then putting the two strings together, sadly this doesn't work if the first of the number is a 1.

```
function steamid(tradelink){
    var numbers = parseInt(tradelink.split('?partner=')[1].split('&')[0]),
            base = '76561197960265728';

    var number = parseInt(base.substr(-(numbers.toString().length + 1))) + numbers;
            steamid = //put back together
}

steamid('https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=912447736&token=qJD0Oui2');
```

Expected:
`76561198872713464`

Comment: Search for node.js big integer libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For doing operations with such big integers, you should use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), it will correctly operate on integers bigger than 2ˆ53 (which is the largest size that normal `Number` can support on JS

```js
const sum = BigInt(76561197960265728) + BigInt(912447736);

console.log(sum.toString());
```

**Edit 2020:** This API still [not widely supported by some browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=bigint), so you may need to have a polyfill, please check [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer)

**Edit 2023** This API is now [supported on almost everything but internet explorer](https://caniuse.com/bigint), so you can probably safely use this without polyfills unless you have strict legacy browser support requirements.

Comment: Woah, this makes life so much easier, thanks a lot! I'll look into it, I thought it wouldn't be possibile because of the way javascript handles large numbers.

Comment: Not very well supported at all - pretty much exclusively Chrome (errors out in latest Safari)

Comment: you can always use polyfills: https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer

Comment: Internet what? Explorer? Never heard of her ;-)