# Summing numbers in javascript gives unexpected value

Tags: javascript

Strangely enough, when I try to add "9333852702227980 + 7", it returns me "9333852702227988" and not "9333852702227987".
I cannot figure out why! Any ideas and how to go around this problem?

```js
alert((9333852702227980 + 7).toString());
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557509/javascript-summing-large-integers

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losin
Your number is higher than the highest integer that is precise.