# Storing BigInt values in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

In SQlServer I have these values stored in the ID -6410551811284209102
2248193693505952772
1897495303850505563

But while fetching it **truncate the value in AngularJS**, Like
for **1897495303850505563** it convert as **1897495303850505500**
for **2248193693505952772** it convert as **2248193693505952800**.
This is because I am storing these values in either number or object. But these are BigInt in SqlServer.
Anybody has any clue for how to store these values in bigInt.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557509/javascript-summing-large-integers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript summing large integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557509/javascript-summing-large-integers)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this javascript library for AngularJS https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer

Comment: But how can we use it in HTML page. I get all the data using AngularJs Get Call, and then binding it in the HTML controls.  So If I am using like this: bigInt(item.USER_ID), it surly throw me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you convert/cast the big int to a string?